# Using a loop to print out Carousel images

Tags: javascript, php

So I'm trying to automate my site to show all the images relating to a item of stock (A vehicle). I am able to show the images but they all come up in one block due to the fact one item needs the active class. Is this possible to automate? Or is there are way of saying use 'active' once in the loop?

Below is the code (UPDATED!), not all of it only the bit I'm working on. Yes I have the jQuery and JavaScript being pulled in!:) Thanks!

```
<?php

            include 'Login-System/db.php';

            $query = 'SELECT * FROM forsale ORDER by StockID ASC';
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

            if($result):
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0):
                    while($forsale = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):

                        ?>

                        <div class="col-md-6" >
                            <div class="forsale">
                                <?php
                                    $match = $forsale['StockID'];

                                    $queryimg = "SELECT * FROM forsaleimg WHERE StockID = ".$match." ORDER BY 'Order' ASC ";
                                    $resultimg = mysqli_query($conn, $queryimg);


                                ?>

                                <!--Image Carousel-->
                                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                    <!-- Indicators -->
                                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                        <?php 
                                            for($i=0; $i <4; $i++){
                                        ?>
                                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i;?>" <?php if ($i == 0) {
                                            echo 'class="active"';
                                        } ?>></li>
                                        <?php   

                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </ol>

                                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="width:auto; height:auto;" >
                                         <?php
                                            $active = 0; 
                                        if($resultimg):
                                            if(mysqli_num_rows($resultimg)>0):
                                                while($forsaleimg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultimg)):

                                                ?>

                                                <div class="carosuel-item <?php if ($active == 0){echo 'active';}?>">
                                                    <img class="d-block w-100 img-responsive" src="<?php echo $forsaleimg['FileDestination']; ?>">
                                                </div>

                                                <?php 
                                                    $active= $active + 1;
                                                endwhile;
                                            endif;
                                        endif;
                                        ?>

                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Left and right controls -->
                                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                    </a>

                                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class carousel-indicators. Simply loop from 0 to 3 and in each iteration output the li you need. If you do a simple for loop (i=0; i<4; i++) etc then you can check if i == 0 and if it is, add the active class to the li.

Comment: So I've updated the code above with your suggestion but Im now getting the issue of the images all showing together [you can see here.](https://gyazo.com/3bd1f8cd84b645fd59da1dab54fdb41a)

Comment: In your code:

if ($active == 0){echo 'active';}

Change to:

if ($active == 0){echo 'active'; $active++}

Otherwise, your variable $active will always stay at 0, so all of the carousel images will apply the active class.